# How do you securely give access to a Java App interactive console (Linux/GNU)?

Tags: linux, integrity, iptables, availability, reverse-shell

I have a Java App running, which prints out messages into STDOUT and also has an active interactive console (also accepts STDIN), when the server has started up.

How do I securely give access to an external person (outside the network) to the console and nothing else?

I was figuring using `ncat --ssl -e java filenamehere`

And setting a firewall rule for the port used to only allow packets from one origin:

`iptables -I INPUT \! --src 1.2.3.4 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 777 -j DROP  # if it's not 1.2.3.4, drop it`

But is that secure?

In theory, IP spoofing can be used or are modern mitigation methods built into the OS? I tried setting `nospoof on` in the host.conf file but it seems that it's obsolete.

I was thinking of giving reverse-shell but that probably is a bit too much and insecure in my opinion. What is your opinion?

Comment: IP spoofing can be used to send packets, but it will not work to receive packets or complete a handshake ...

Comment: `host.conf` doesn't apply ...

Comment: why do you think reverse shell is insecure?

Comment: Authentication is the way to provide connections and ensure that only authorised users can connect... Network-level controls have limitations. IP whitelisting suffers from the problem of IPs changing.

Comment: @schroeder so IP spoofing can't be used to do a TLS handshake? I think reverse shell is insecure because arbitrary code could get executed on the server. How do I provide authentication then? Maybe something along the lines of nginx proxy basic auth, but then I would need to host it as a web page..

Comment: no, you cannot complete a handshake when spoofing - how on earth can you get the server response?

Comment: or add authentication to your app ...

Comment: There are lots of proxy options that do not require that the target be a webpage.

Comment: I am apparently not that experienced with using nginx as a proxy or any proxy at all. Could you give me a reference on how to do that? AFAIK, the user would still need to put up the browser for auth. Perfectly, it would be better off without a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IP addresses really aren't suitable for authentication, you should implement something else to do the job. A simple example in your scenario would be to write a wrapper script (executed by netcat or socat) that prompts for credentials. If the credentials are correct, it can then exec your Java program. This could be done in a few lines with a Bash script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

CORRECT_PASSWORD='h7a0&7;ngIl1+'
MYPROG="java filenamehere"
echo -n "Enter password: "
read -s pass

if [[ "$pass" == "$CORRECT_PASSWORD" ]]; then
    exec "$MYPROG"
else 
    echo Password incorrect
fi
```

You could run this in an endless loop with:

```
socat openssl-l:1234,reuseaddr,fork,certificate=cert.pem,keyfile=key.pem exec:/usr/local/bin/myscript
```

You do not need to worry about IP spoofing when using TCP in most cases, so whitelisting allowed addresses can be part of a defense-in-depth solution for your application.

Now, this is all assuming you fully trust the other person to use your application and your application is otherwise sufficiently locked down.

Comment: The problem is that the bash script running the app is a bit complicated and includes restart functionality (if the server crashes), backups etc. Also, could you explain the architecture a bit more? I am a bit confused about it. Could you give an example in bash then?

Comment: Maybe executing my script with auth included (not sure how I do that with bash maybe with expect?) with websocketd is a good solution?

Comment: @SirMuffington not sure what existing script you are talking about, but I added a very simple example

Comment: I guess I can exec the script instead of directly executing `java etc`. The script contains the `java filename parameters etc` in a bash function. It would also be awesome if you could explain the socat comma-separated parameters.

Comment: Also, does socat work across the internet?

Comment: @SirMuffington there are a lot of options, so I'd suggest viewing the manpage. But, fork will keep the socket running and fork off your program each time a connection is made, reuseaddr is a socket option that effectively makes it quicker to restart, the rest of the options point to cert & keys for TLS. The second part with exec that script every time it's connected to

Comment: @SirMuffington yes, barring any firewalls, it is reachable like any network daemon

Comment: Thank you. One question does remain though: how do you connect to this interface?

Comment: @SirMuffington same way you'd connect to a netcat listener; netcat is one way to do it

Comment: Isn't the bash script vulnerable to side-channel attacks (timing attack to be precise)?

Comment: @SirMuffington what makes you say that?

Comment: Doesn't bash have different timing according to the amount of correctly or incorrectly typed in characters?

Comment: @SirMuffington interesting, haven't heard of that. You could always hash and compare against a hashed password instead.

Comment: I'm guessing the hashing has to be async as well for it to be not vulnerable against timing attacks. Which doesn't truly exist in Bash AFAIK... or does adding a & at the end of the command make it async and safe enough?